# Django: delete object when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I'd like to delete objects when the table row is checked in Django. After following answers on Stackoverflow, I've got the code below. However, it doesn't delete the objects of the model. I log the code; the onclick delete button works. It calls delete_test function, but the test model isn't delete. The terminal says

> Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.):
>   /test-management/delete_test/

Thank in advance!

**urls.py**

```
from test_management.views import (test_list, add_test
                                    , delete_test)

urlpatterns = [url(r'^test-management/test/', test_list, name='test'),
    url(r'^test-management/add_test/', add_test, name='add_test'),
    url(r'^test-management/delete_test/', delete_test, name='delete_test'),]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**views.py**

```
def delete_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        selected_tests = request.POST['test_list_ids']
        selected_tests = json.loads(selected_tests)
        for i, test in enumerate(selected_tests):
            if test != '':
                Test.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('items')).delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/test-management/test/')
```

**test_list.html**

```
</button>
    <button class="btn btn-round delete-btn" data-toggle="modal">
  <i class="material-icons" action >delete</i>   Delete
</button>

<div class="table-container">
            <table id="fresh-table" class="table table-striped test-list">
                    <thead class="thead-table-list">
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">
                          <div class="form-check">
                              <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" id="checkall" type="checkbox" value="">
                                <span class="form-check-sign">
                                  <span class="check"></span>
                                </span>
                              </label>
                          </div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Test</th>
                        <th scope="col">Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Test Date</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for test in tests %}
                        <tr data-id="{{ test.id }}">
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                        <input class="form-check-input check-ele" type="checkbox" value="">
                                        <span class="form-check-sign">
                                        <span class="check"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </label>
                                  </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ test.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{ test.test_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{ test.test_type}}</td>
                            <td>{{ test.test_date}}</td>  
                        </tr>      
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(".delete-btn").click(function(){

  var selected_rows=[];

  $('.test-list').find('tr').each(function(){
    var row=$(this);
    console.log(row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'));
    if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
        console.log(row.attr('data-id'));
        selected_rows.push(row.attr('data-id'));
        };
    });
    var selected_rows = JSON.stringify(selected_rows);
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'delete_test' %}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'test_list_ids': selected_rows},
    })
});
</script>
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: Thank you. I've follow the documentation. It works but get me sometimes to understand it @DanielRoseman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `csrfmiddlewaretoken` along with the POST data. You can do this by including the template tag `{% csrf_token %}`.

```
</button>
    <button class="btn btn-round delete-btn" data-toggle="modal">
  <i class="material-icons" action >delete</i>   Delete
</button>

<div class="table-container">
            <table id="fresh-table" class="table table-striped test-list">
                    <thead class="thead-table-list">
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">
                          <div class="form-check">
                              <label class="form-check-label">
                                <input class="form-check-input" id="checkall" type="checkbox" value="">
                                <span class="form-check-sign">
                                  <span class="check"></span>
                                </span>
                              </label>
                          </div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                        <th scope="col">Test</th>
                        <th scope="col">Type</th>
                        <th scope="col">Test Date</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {% for test in tests %}
                        <tr data-id="{{ test.id }}">
                            <td>
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <label class="form-check-label">
                                        <input class="form-check-input check-ele" type="checkbox" value="">
                                        <span class="form-check-sign">
                                        <span class="check"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </label>
                                  </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ test.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{ test.test_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{ test.test_type}}</td>
                            <td>{{ test.test_date}}</td>  
                        </tr>      
                        {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
{% csrf_token %}
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
$(".delete-btn").click(function(){

  var selected_rows=[];

  $('.test-list').find('tr').each(function(){
    var row=$(this);
    console.log(row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked'));
    if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
        console.log(row.attr('data-id'));
        selected_rows.push(row.attr('data-id'));
        };
    });
    var selected_rows = JSON.stringify(selected_rows);
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'delete_test' %}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'test_list_ids': selected_rows,'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()},
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is solved by passing a `csrfmiddlewaretoken` along with the POST data. You can do this by including the template tag `{% csrf_token %}`

```
$.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'delete_test' %}",
        type: 'POST',
        data: {'test_list_ids': selected_rows,'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()},
    })
```

I also get to delete object of the model when row's checkbox is checked and delete button is click- by editing:

**views.py**

```
def delete_test(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        selected_tests = request.POST['test_list_ids']
        selected_tests = json.loads(selected_tests)
        for i, test in enumerate(selected_tests):
            if test != '':
                Test.objects.filter(id__in=selected_tests).delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/test-management/test/')
```

Thanks!